# How to preserve HTML table style & on:click property after DataTables Ajax reload?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a table created via `Thymeleaf` with set class & `th:onclick` property.

I am doing table data reload after a new entry is added to the database. The reload is done via Ajax reading the json file and applying the changes via `table.ajax.reload`.

After the reload I seem to lose all the styling and onclick property as it just doesn't trigger.

My html table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="main-table">

<thead class="thead-inverse">
<tr>
    <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Network Id</th>
    <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Rep date</th>
    <th class="col-md-2 text-center">Hashrate [KH/s]</th>
</tr>
</thead>

 <tbody>
 <tr style="cursor: pointer;" th:each="networkHashrate : ${networkHashrates}" th:onclick="'javascript:openPoolModal(\''+ ${networkHashrate.id} + '\');'">
     <td class="text-center" id="hashrateId" th:text="${networkHashrate.id}"> Sample id</td>
     <td class="text-center" id="repDate" th:text="${@findAndDisplayDataService.formatDate(networkHashrate.repDate)}">Sample rep-date</td>
     <td class="text-center" id="hashrate" th:text="${@findAndDisplayDataService.formatHashrate(networkHashrate.hashrate)}">Sample hashrate</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

 </table>
```

A function that does the reload:

```
var table;

$(document).ready(function() {
table = $('#main-table').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '/refresh',
                //type: 'json',
                dataSrc:''
            },
           paging: true,
           lengthChange: false,
           pageLength: 20,
           stateSave: true,
           info: true,
           searching: false,
           "columnDefs": [
                               {
                                   "className": "text-center",
                                   "targets": 0,
                                   "data": "id",
                               },
                               {
                                   "className": "text-center",
                                   "targets": 1,
                                   "data": "repDate.year",
                               },
                               {
                                   "className": "text-center",
                                   "targets": 2,
                                   "data": "hashrate",
                               }
                           ],
           "aoColumns": [
             { "orderSequence": [ "asc", "desc" ] },
             { "orderSequence": [ "asc", "desc" ] },
             { "orderSequence": [ "desc", "asc" ] }
           ],
           "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]


});
});

setInterval(function(){
table.ajax.reload(null, false);
}, 8000);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, using `Datatable` replaces the existing `<tbody>` completely, including all the extra Thymeleaf template HTML you have. If you want to retain that, you cannot use Datatable. You don't really need it anyway; just load the AJAX data into your Thymeleaf data structure.

Comment: I have literally no idea on how to do that. Any clues?

Comment: From my ten seconds of research on Thymeleaf it's server-side Java templating. Which means your `th:each`, `th:text`, etc. code is used on the server, to render data as HTML that exists on the server. It follows that you need to ditch `Datatable`, and instead make an AJAX request for the entire table, and let Thymeleaf fill it with data on the server.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the problem is I can't really render another `html` file as generating table from Json uses less resources than sending a newly generated html. That's why they want me to use front-end only techniques...

Comment: In that case you have to set onclick handlers and other properties using jQuery. For instance: `$('#main-table').on("click", "tr", ...);`